# Should the 'vc' tag be made a synonym for 'visual-c++'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I recently came across the [vc](/questions/tagged/vc) tag with just under 200 questions. The proclaimed purpose of the tag is "Short for Microsoft Visual C++. It is a C and C++ compiler for Windows." I tried to find the questions with the [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) tag, which redirected to [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b), with nearly 16,000 questions. The proclaimed purpose of the tag is "Microsoft Visual C++ is a C and C++ compiler for Windows".

- Is there a significant difference in meaning between the [vc](/questions/tagged/vc) and [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b) tags?

  - *I don't think so, but other people may be able to spot a valuable difference.*
- If not, should the [vc](/questions/tagged/vc) be made a synonym of [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [vc](/questions/tagged/vc) tag is now a synonym for [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b).

Comment: Hat whoring, eh?

Comment: It seems to be a legitimate case of sock puppetry...It is more in the way of a status update, but I'll take the hat too.

Comment: so much sock puppetry that you're the same person. Wow. ;)

Comment: Also, for whatever it is worth, either MSO is very slow at handing out hats, or you only get a Sock Puppet hat if you ask the question during Winter Bash as well as answer it — or it may be that you have to specify that you're going to answer your own question as you ask it, or ... well, I haven't yet got a Sock Puppet hat to wear.  Sniff!  Boohoo...